# Xenforo Navigation

Tags: php, html, forum, xenforo

How would I have a specific node display on the navigation?

For example I'm the web developer for a minecraft network and we want to add our vote page onto the navigation, of course we could just hard code it using an anchor into the navigation template, but when it's clicked on, it wouldn't show that 'Vote' is the active page.

I appreciate any responses.

Answer (score 0):

XenForo doesn't support that by default but you can do that by using a 3rd party add-on. I would suggest using one of the following add-ons.

[Nodes As Tabs](https://xenforo.com/community/resources/nodes-as-tabs.9/)
OR
[Custom Tabs](https://xenforo.com/community/resources/custom-tabs.4117/)